Как мне сделать интерактивное пуш уведомление на React Native
Всем привет, на работе дали задание сделать пуши для нашего приложения более интерактивными. Приложение на react native. Сначала сделал все используя библиотеку Notifee, но там просто пуши и две кнопки, а теперь надо сделать так чтобы кнопки можно было стилизовать, расположить по разному, прокидывать в них данные, нарисовать доп интерфейс и прогресс бар с бэка прокидывать. В качестве примера дали уведомления от яндекс го и надо подобное реализовать у нас. Подскажите как мне это сделать, в какую сторону копать и вообще реализуемо ли это на react native. Основная проблема для меня - я не понимаю как это отрисовать и стилизовать.
Пробовал библиотеку notifee. Ожидаю результат примерно как на фото

